# Obtener el valor de un HTML input tipo arreglo sin necesidad de usar post mediante formulario

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo el código HTML:

```html
<table id="detalles" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
    <thead style="background-color:#A9D0F5">
        <tr>
            <th>Opciones</th>
            <th>Bloque</th>
            <th>Articulo</th>
        </tr>
  </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="filas" id="fila0">
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminarDetalle(0)">X</button></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="bloque[]" value="1" />2112954</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="idarticulo[]" value="1" />AC</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="filas" id="fila1">
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="eliminarDetalle(1)">X</button></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="bloque[]" value="1" />2112954</td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="idarticulo[]" value="1" />AB</td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Necesito obtener para **jQuery** de los **inputs** `idarticulo` y `bloque` sin necesidad de hacer un **POST**.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar un poco mejor qué es lo que necesitas? También otra duda que me surgió es: ¿Cómo deseas obtener esos datos? ¿Cuando se le dé click a la fila? ¿Un click a algún botón en específico? Si pudieras brindar un boceto sobre cómo quisieras ese proceso o acción sería de mucha ayuda.

Comment: Lo que neceisto es obtener la información que contienen los input idarticulo y bolque ( mediante el nombre o el id ), el proceso es como  bien indicas usando un botón para obtener dicha información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya intentaste con añadirle una clase al boton, luego capturar la clase y en base a ella disparar un evento on click?

Quizás esto te funcione:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.btnEliminarDetalle').on('click', function(){
 var bloque = $(this).parent().siblings('td').find('input[name="bloque[]"]').val();
 var idArticulo = $(this).parent().siblings('td').find('input[name="idarticulo[]"]').val();
 console.log('bloque: ', bloque);
 console.log('id Articulo: ', idArticulo);

})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="detalles" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
  <thead style="background-color:#A9D0F5">
    <tr>
      <th>Opciones</th>
      <th>Bloque</th>
      <th>Articulo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="filas" id="fila0">
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btnEliminarDetalle">X</button></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="bloque[]" value="1">2112954</td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="idarticulo[]" value="1">AC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filas" id="fila1">
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btnEliminarDetalle" >X</button></td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="bloque[]" value="1">2112954</td>
      <td><input type="hidden" name="idarticulo[]" value="1">AB</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Ejecuta el snippet y da click en los botones te saldra un console.log, ya de ahi pues le das la funcion que desees...

Saludos.

Comment: Me fuciono, muchas gracias por tu apoyo.